How to blend two different normals from two different materials
As the tile says how to make the ends of two different normals merge to look seamless. The image shows the problem I'm dealing with and would like to know if fixing this can be handled within blender. Link to file below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PCpckpxKfnLc5Cbz-IkM302d3okVr3Ir/view?usp=sharing



Hello it's not clear where the problem comes from, could you please pack the images and share your file?

Added file to post.

The arm has another material assigned to it (called _188), the color is the same but it has a different normal map and it doesn't look like it joints correctly with the normal map of the shoulder material (called _172). So you need to fix that by giving the whole body the same material with the correct unwrap, or simply unplug the Normal Map nodes from the Principled BSDF.
Or what you could do is plug the 2 normal map directly into the Output, and paint the joints with a blue color that you've picked up with the eyedropper.

So I'm fairly new to blender or 3d as a whole so I'm not really sure what you refer to for unwrapping.

A normal is basically a Vector, so in Shader Nodes you would blend them by using the Vector Math node.
For your model you can try to go into Edit mode, press A to highlight all vertices and then go to Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside I think.
Also have a look if any of the other menu points under Normals might be of use for your particular problem.

Tried your suggestions nothing helped with problem also wasn't sure what setup you where referring to for the math node thing.
